TK B777 seat map confusion about exit row
I am flying on the TK flight from Istanbul to Bombay. This is a B777 and the SeatGuru Seat map as well as the TK website say that Row 40 is an exit row.
https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Turkish_Airlines/Turkish_Airlines_Boeing_777-300_V3.php
However just a few days ago I flew the reverse flight BOM to IST and got myself Row 43 as an exit row.
I'm confused. Are there two seat layouts? Is the Istanbul to Bombay flight special somehow?
Anyone know whether row 40 is an exit row or Row 43?

There are indeed (at least) two versions, 77W and 77K, and you may get one or the other depending on the date. When are you flying? It looks like Seat Guru isn’t up to date and only has one version of TK’s 777.


Are there two seat layouts?

Yes. That's very normal. Airlines fly different configurations on the same airplane type to accommodate different seat type requirements on different routes. United for example flies 5 different versions of the B777.

Is the Istanbul to Bombay flight special somehow?

No. Aircraft types are mapped to routes based on schedule, demand and based on availability and positioning of the aircraft.
Unfortunately seatguru.com has either fallen out of maintenance altogether or is very slow to update and a lot of newer configurations don't show up there.
Your best shot is to check seat maps directly at the airline's website but availability is all over the place and Turkish does not seem to offer detailed maps.
Another alternative is https://www.aerolopa.com/tk (no affiliation) which shows indeed two different versions with exit rows being indeed 40 and 43 respectively.
